# Angular $q.all gets called after first promise finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to use $q.all to wait until all promises are resolved but it's called after first promise is finished!

What I'm doing wrong?

```
function sendAudits(audits) {
    var promises = [];

    $scope.sendAudits = {
        progress: 0
    };
    angular.forEach(audits, function (audit, idAudit) {
        promises.push(saveAudit(audit));
    });

    $q
        .all(promises)
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, function (errors) {
            console.log(errors);
        });
}

function saveAudit(audit) {
    var filename = audit.header.id + ".txt";

    return $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '/audits/audits.php?filename=' + encodeURIComponent(filename),
        data: AuditSvc.getPlainAudit(audit.header.id)
    }).finally(function () {
        $scope.sendAudits.progress += 1;
        console.log("FINALLY: " + audit.header.id);
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

Analysing a little bit deeper the problem, this situation occurs when some of the responses are error. For example when the server returns `header("HTTP/1.0 418 I'm A Teapot: " . $filename);`, client console would be like:

```
PUT http://localhost:8182/audits/audits.php?filename=1.txt 418 (I'm A Teapot: 1.txt)
FINALLY: 1
Object {data: "", status: 418, config: Object, statusText: "I'm A Teapot: 1.txt"}
PUT http://localhost:8182/audits/audits.php?filename=2.txt 418 (I'm A Teapot: 2.txt)
FINALLY: 2
PUT http://localhost:8182/audits/audits.php?filename=3.txt 418 (I'm A Teapot: 3.txt)
FINALLY: 3
PUT http://localhost:8182/audits/audits.php?filename=4.txt 418 (I'm A Teapot: 4.txt)
FINALLY: 4
```

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: The response for the first call to saveAudit: first $http call (audits has 4 elements). The strange is that progress get's raised 4 times in `finally` (one for each audit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular documentation doesn't go into detail, but I believe `$q.all()` behaves in this case the same way as the es2015 `Promise.all()`:

> If any of the passed in promises rejects, the all Promise immediately rejects with the value of the promise that rejected, discarding all the other promises whether or not they have resolved.

Most likely what is happening here is that at least one of your requests is failing. Your log statements don't distinguish whether the `$q.all()` succeeded or failed but if it is failing all you will see is the first error.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all for the source of the quote.

**Edit:**

If you want to get all of the responses, even when some fail, then you should add a `catch` handler in `saveAudit` to convert the failures into successful responses:

```
function saveAudit(audit) {
    var filename = audit.header.id + ".txt";

    return $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '/audits/audits.php?filename=' + encodeURIComponent(filename),
        data: AuditSvc.getPlainAudit(audit.header.id)
    }).catch(function(error) {
        return { error:error};
    })
    .finally(function () {
        $scope.sendAudits.progress += 1;
        console.log("FINALLY: " + audit.header.id);
    });
}
```

and then you need to check each response to see whether it contains an error or valid data.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've just noticed (see edit in the question). Do you know any way to bypass this behavior? Also I've seen that if all promises are rejected, the catch callback is called just once, not with all errors. At least one would expect that error callback is called with all errors, not just with the first one...

Comment: If you want to get all the error you need to convert them into successes. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

### `$q.all` is **not resilient**

As noted by others, `$q.all` is **not resilient**. If one of the promises is rejected, the `$q.all` is rejected with the first error.

To create a **resilient** composite promise, that is a promise that waits for all the promises to complete pass or fail, use `.catch` on each individual promise to **convert** the rejected promise to a successful promise.

```
var resilientPromises = [];

angular.forEach(promises, function(p) {
    var resilientP = p.catch( function(result) {
        //return to convert rejection to success
        return result;
    });
    resilientPromises.push(resilientP);
});

$q.all(resilientPromises).then( function (results) {
    //process results
});
```

The two things to take away from this answer:

1. A `$q.all` promise is **not resilient**. It is rejected with the first rejected promise.
2. A fulfilled promise can be created from a rejected promise by **returning** a value to the onRejected function of either the `.then` method or the `.catch` method.

For more information, see [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)

Comment: +1 for the resilient solution. I had solved with another `$q.defer()` that was resolved in any case, but with `return` clause I think it's simpler.

Comment: it should be `angular.forEach`