# How to check the state of an angular-promise?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

In my website, I have API's for twitter and facebook which enables the "mentions" feature (the one that pops up whenever we use the @ symbol)

However, it is often that the access token for some feature is often expires  resulting in the API not working. I store all my API's in an array and then I need to check if the token has failed or not resulting in resolved or rejected API promise.

This is an older code that needs changing due $q.all. As $q.all works whenever all the promises have been resolved, thus triggering the .then() call, this results in the .then() function NEVER working in my case (as the Facebook API is never working)

I need to find a condition where each API is checked and the .then() runs for only that API that is resolved (twitter in this case) and ignores the failed API (Facebook in this case)

```
        if (selectedIds.allowed.TW) {
          usersApi.push(TS.loginResource.getTwitterProfiles({
            subUserId: selectedIds.allowed.TW,
            name: searchTerm
          }).$promise);
        }

        if (selectedIds.allowed.FB || selectedIds.allowed.FB_PAGE || 
            selectedIds.allowed.FB_GROUP) {
          $scope.post.showTags = true;
          usersApi.push(TS.loginResource.getFbPages({
            subUserId: selectedIds.allowed.FB_PAGE || selectedIds.allowed.FB 
            || selectedIds.allowed.FB_GROUP,
            name: searchTerm
          }).$promise);
        }


        if (usersApi.length) {
          $q.all(usersApi).then(function (responses) {
            var tags1 = responses[0];
            tags1.forEach(function (tag, i) {
              tags1[i].name = tag.name.replace(/\"/g, "");
            });
            $scope.post.tags = tags1;
            if (usersApi.length > 1) {
              var tags2 = responses[1]
              tags2.forEach(function (tag, i) {
                tags2[i].name = tag.name.replace(/\"/g, "");
              });
              $scope.post.tags = $scope.post.tags.concat(tags2);
            }
          })
        }
      }, 500);
    } else {
      $scope.post.tags = [];
      $scope.post.showTags = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking to chain backup response that catch the api error and return a new success resolved promise on each specific api call before you wait on "all" of them.

```
apiCalls.push(doTwiterStuff().then(handleTwiterSuccess, handleApiFailure);
apiClass.push(doFBStuff().then(handleFbSuccess, handleApiFailure);

Promise.all(apiCalls).then(arr => {
  arr.filter(x => !isNil(x)).forEach(x => doSomethingWithApiResult(x));
});

function handleApiFailure(x) {
  ...
  return Promise.resolve(null);
}
```

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Forgive me if i ask an unintelligent question; I am just a beginner in angularjs and i am still trying to wrap my head around API concepts, but how am I supposed to 'handleTwiterSuccess' and 'handleApiFailure'. Are there any built in methods or do I have to explicitly write functions for it?

Comment: also, by apiCalls, you mean usersApi?

Comment: Those are just filler names for your implementation functions or anonymous functions. If you need custom success handling specific to twitter/facebook etc. handleApiFailure is also a custom function you wirte. What is important is that handleApiFailure or anonymous function return a Promise.resolve instead of Promise.reject. That way Promise.all will get resolved.

Comment: Yes, apiCalls is just my name for your usersApi

Comment: But that exactly isn't what I wish to achieve. By resolving all the promises, I will fail to differentiate the failing promises (ones with the expired tokens) versus the ones with the successful ones (ones with existing tokens). The problem with $q.all was that it worked only for resolved promises. How is this different from the previous case?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. the 'handleApiFailure' turns the failed promise into a successful one that returns null instead of error. Then all the promises that Promise.all gets are resolved successfully but with some returning nulls that you can filter on.

Comment: and the 'handleApiSuccess' returns the successful promise as an array element? (userApi in this case)

Comment: the handleApiSuccess returns what you want to do with specific result. As long as it returns it as Promise.resolve(someValue) so it will be promise also. ex `handeFacebookSuccess = (fbResult) => { return Promise.resolve({ myTag: 'facebook', result: fbResult }); `

Answer (score 1):

### `$q.all` is **not resilient**<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34881821/5535245)</sup>

If one of the promises is rejected, the `$q.all` is rejected with the first error.

To create a **resilient** composite promise, that is a promise that waits for all the promises to complete pass or fail, use `.catch` on each individual promise to **convert** the rejected promise to a successful promise.

```
var resilientPromises = [];

angular.forEach(promises, function(p) {
    var resilientP = p.catch( function(result) {
        //return to convert rejection to success
        return result;
    });
    resilientPromises.push(resilientP);
});

$q.all(resilientPromises).then( function (results) {
    //process results
});
```

The two things to take away from this answer:

1. A `$q.all` promise is **not resilient**. It is rejected with the first rejected promise.
2. A fulfilled promise can be created from a rejected promise by **returning** a value to the onRejected function of either the `.then` method or the `.catch` method.